# Indices of sorted array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2 dimensional Array with shape (nrows,ncols) containing real numbers. I would like get the indices (row,col) corresponding to the Array values in decreasing order. Checking the documentaion of np.argsort(), it seems that it only returns the indices ordered by a specific axis. Im sure that that this should be simple but i just cant figure it out.

For example, if i have:

```
[
[1   5   6]
[7   4   9]
[8   2   3]
]
```

the desired output would be:

```
[
(1,2),
(2,0),
(1,0),
(0,2),
(0,1),
(1,1),
(2,2),
(2,1),
(0,0),
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way for descending order -

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 5, 6],
       [7, 4, 9],
       [8, 2, 3]])

In [20]: np.c_[np.unravel_index(a.ravel().argsort()[::-1],a.shape)]
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

For ascending order, skip the flipping part : `[::-1]`.

Or with negative values -

```
In [24]: np.c_[np.unravel_index((-a).ravel().argsort(),a.shape)]
Out[24]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder, why the case of negative values ? The first example seems to work for both.

Comment: @JustANoob WIth negative values, the argsort would get the indices in the flipped order. That's lets us skip the flipping. That's just an alternative here.